# Passing a model instance to another model's function

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, parameter-passing

So here is a piece of code I have right now that is working and inside one of my Controllers:

```
auth()->user()->confirmReservation(
  new Reservation(request(['room_id', 'data_ini', 'data_fin']))
);
```

And this is the method in my Users Model:

```
public function confirmReservation(Reservation $reservation) {
  $this->reservations()->save($reservation);
}
```

I'd like to add a variable as another parameter to that object and I couldn't find an answer to this online. I'm new to Laravel and I know this must be pretty basic. Can anybody help me? Some guidance so I can improve as a programmer would be much appreciated too. Thank you!

Comment: where you want to add the parameter ? i didn't get you

Comment: At the new Reservation(...) line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the parameters from the request as an array, then add additional parameters.

```
$params = request(['room_id', 'data_ini', 'data_fin']);
$params['foo'] = 'bar'; // <-- Add another parameter

auth()->user()->confirmReservation(
  new Reservation($params)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
auth()->user()->confirmReservation(
    new Reservation($request->only('room_id', 'data_ini', 'data_fin')+['another_parameter'=>$anotherParameter])
);
```